# Faulty NMI implementation in R?

Tags: r

```
#calculate NMI(c,t) c : cluster assignment , t : ground truth

NMI <- function(c,t){
n <- length(c) # = length(t)
r <- length(unique(c))
g <- length(unique(t))

N <- matrix(0,nrow = r , ncol = g)
for(i in 1:r){
    for (j in 1:g){
        N[i,j] = sum(t[c == i] == j)
    }
}

N_t <- colSums(N)
N_c <- rowSums(N)

B <- (1/n)*log(t( t( (n*N) / N_c ) / N_t))
W <- B*N
I <- sum(W,na.rm = T) 



H_c <- sum((1/n)*(N_c * log(N_c/n)) , na.rm = T)
H_t <- sum((1/n)*(N_t * log(N_t/n)) , na.rm = T)    

nmi <- I/sqrt(H_c * H_t)

return (nmi)
}
```

Running this on some clustering benchmarks [here](http://cs.joensuu.fi/sipu/datasets/) gives me a value of the  Normalized Mutual information  . But , when I compare it with values of NMI  obtained from the aricode library , I get values of NMI that generally differ in the second decimal place .

I will be grateful if someone is able to pin-point any possible error that has creeped into this code .

I am including a test case for this using a synthetic case :

```
library(aricode)
c <- c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4)
t <- c(1,2,2,2,3,4,3,3,3,4,4,2)
print(aricode::NMI(c , t))   #0.489574
print(NMI(c,t))              #0.5030771
```

Comment: I think you'll be more likely to get responses and interest if you make this question self-contained. For that, please include input data and expected output. Requiring us to go to a link is a low probability of success: often links go stale, rendering the page unhelpful to follow-on askers; and some people (myself included) are at least a little averse to go to arbitrary sites and/or download arbitrary links/files. Keeping this small, self-contained, and fully reproducible helps the whole process. Thanks!

Comment: Ok thanks for your input . I am including the code for testing a particular case ! Please hang on :)

Comment: You're asking somebody to do a full audit of your 18+ lines against `aricode`'s 114 lines or so for the trace through `NMI`, `entropy`, `sortPairs`, and `countPairs`. Sorry, I don't have the time or motivation to dive that far into it now. I suggest you try to reimplement each function, compare outputs, and continue from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be very late for an answer but for the sake of posterity:

The difference is in the way you and the `aricode` package normalise the index. You divide by `sqrt()` whereas `aricode` offers the following options:
`function (c1, c2, variant = c("max", "min", "sqrt", "sum", "joint"))`

so if you select `variant = sqrt` you should hopefully get the same answer.

The `NMI` package uses sum.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! It's indeed a bit late, but better late than never :)